# Can't load tflite custom model into web using react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have 2 tflite models hosted as s3 objects on aws. In my react-typescript app, I am trying to load those models if the browser is opened on mobile. Else, the web app will use other more efficient models.
[image]

The `Models` interface is as follows:
[image]

I have configured the s3 bucket so I can access it from this web app, by changing the CORS configuration. That works. If I go to the network tabs, I see the fetch for the model:

[image]

Using Chrome, I can change from mobile to desktop display. The desktop display does not produce any errors. However, the mobile gives me errors that I do not understand.

[image]

Ignore the `GET` error and the `date_created` console.log. They are from another part of my code that is not relevant to this.

I have searched various resources for deploying a tflite to a web app, but have not found anything useful.

------------------**EDIT**-------------------

I have tried using the method discussed in [this github post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6026)
[image]

But only get the following error (you can ignore the GET error and isMobile console.log):

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are looking something like this https://www.tensorflow.org/js and not use tflite file for web?

Comment: @Farmaker I have already added a tensorflow js model to the web app. The thing is that for a browser on mobile, I want to use the tflite model. That is why I am checking in the first picture if the browser is in mobile or desktop. I have tried using the tensorflow js model for mobile browser but it does not run smoothly. I suspect it is too much computation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that the s3 objects were not uploaded correctly. The script that created the tflite model did not fully created the tflite models. It only created an empty file. I fixed the script. Here is the code that worked:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/R_keypoint_classifier_final.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
r_file = open("tflite_models/R_converted_model.tflite", "wb")
r_file.write(tflite_model)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/L_keypoint_classifier_final.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
l_file = open("tflite_models/L_converted_model.tflite", "wb")
l_file.write(tflite_model)
```

After that, I just added the files to the s3 bucket and used the code with the `setWasmPath` function.

Answer (score 6):

Under the hood, the Tensorflow TFLite API uses WASM (WebAssembly). By default, it will try to load the relevant WASM files from the directory where the bundled JS file lives. This error indicates the files, and therefore the WASM Modules, could not be found. To address this issue, the path where the WASM files are located need to be configured using `tflite.setWasmPath` prior to trying to load the model:

```
tflite.setWasmPath(
   'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite@0.0.1-alpha.8/dist/'
);
```

Alternatively, if you want to serve the WASM files from your own server, you can copy them to the `public` directory in your project:

```
mkdir -p public/tflite_wasm
cp -rf node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite/dist/tflite_web* public/tflite_wasm
```

Then set the path accordingly:

```
tflite.setWasmPath('tflite_wasm/');
```

## Update

Regarding the error you're seeing after adding the `setWasmPath` as detailed in the [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6026) and my initial response, based on the message  "Failed to create TFLiteWebModelRunner: INVALID ARGUMENT" and looking at the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-tflite/src/tflite_model.ts#L329), the error is related to the parameter `model`, which is the model (s3 path) being supplied.

Based on the image you provided showing network activity, it looks like the `R_converted_model.tflite` is downloaded successfully, but  `L_converted_model.tflite` is not in that list. Without having access to the model files to fully reproduce the issue, I would say first verify the `L_converted_model.tflite` file exists at that path in S3. I was able to reproduce the error you're seeing in [this codepen demo](https://codepen.io/jinjingforever/pen/xxgWRaE) by modifying the model path to a non-existent file:

[image: Notice the model file has been changes to 'nonexistent_model.tflite']

If the file does exist at that location, I would evaluate the model file itself by downloading it locally and trying to load it with the [Tensorflow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference), to identify if there is an issue with the file.

Comment: I have tried adding setWasmPath to the cdn path you provided, and it still producess an error. I had actually already tried that method (it appear on this source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6026 )

The error that appears is: 
DevTools failed to load source map: 

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to create TFLiteWebModelRunner: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Can't initialize model

Comment: Can you post more around that error or maybe a screenshot?

Comment: I just edited the question to include the error I explained above

Comment: I have just resolve the issue. the problem was that for some reason, when I uploaded the models to the s3 bucket, they were not properly converted. They had no content. I went back to my script that did the conversion and fixed it. Now it works perfectly.